# PHP include files with parse errors

Tags: php, include

I've got an dynamically-generated PHP file that is included (via include) in other PHP script. When the first one (for some obscure reason) is generated with parse-errors, causes the main script parse-error an stop the execution.

Is there any way to detect parse errors when including a file so I can regenerate dynamically that file?

Comment: Sounds like you need to address the issues that are causing parse-errors in the included script.  I'm not sure about detecting them, but if it errors once, it would seem that it would error again if it was regenerated with the same method.

Comment: There are other situations in which you can get an incorrect file, situations like a power outage or server fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the command line version of PHP to check the syntax:

```
php -l filename
```

If you need to check the syntax from within the PHP script, use the `exec()` function to call the command line program.

See also the deprecated function [`php_check_syntax()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php)

Comment: This is deprecated after 5.0.4

Comment: Just noticed that...changed my answer.

Comment: I would imagine a function call like `php_check_syntax()` would be a lot faster than spawning a new process.. too bad its gone now :(

Answer (score 1):

SYNTAX.php?filename.php

WHERE SYNTAX.php is:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

include($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could execute (using [exec()](http://php.net/exec) or similar) `php -l file.php` and look at the result. It would be slow I would think to do this on every include.

Would it not be better to fix whatever is causing you to generate PHP files which are sometimes invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that will go through my code tree and look for syntax errors. Its not very advanced, but the basics of it is

```
 $cmd="php -l " . $basedir . $dir . "/" . $file;
 $s=exec($cmd,$k);
 if( strstr($s,"No syntax errors detected") ) { include($basedir.$dir."/".$file); }
```

This runs php -l on the script you are about to include, and if there are no errrors loads it.

Answer (score 0):

By executing shell_exec(), you can see the output as if you executed that file via command line. You can just see if there is an error right here.

```
<?php
if (strpos(shell_exec('php -l file.php'), 'Syntax Error')) {
    die('An error!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that you always generate correctly parseable code (which should be easy to achieve with proper escaping, etc), then the only way it can go wrong is when the process of writing the file is interrupted (e.g. a power outage, out of memory condition, process killed, etc.). In that case you will end up with a partial file.

You can protect against these partial writes by adding a signature at the end of the file and checking for its presence before calling include().

For example, if you write `<?php $complete=1; ?>` at the end, you can check for its presence later:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
if (strpos($contents, '<?php $complete=1; ?>')) {
    include($path);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do a `file_get_contents` and then scan it to see if there are any parse errors.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
if (stripos($contents, 'Parse error:') !== 0)
{
  // There was a parse error.
} else {
  // There were no parse errors.
}
```

Comment: won't file_get_contents() just give you php code if $path is a filename ?