# Excecuting exec(php -l *) on OSX

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to run the php CLI from an AJAX call in PHP.  I have it working fine on Windows under WAMP but when I try to run the same exact code under OSX it hangs on the exec() command.  The actual string that it is trying to run on the command line works perfectly in terminal.  I can also run other commands through exec() and they work fine.  So, I am just wondering if anyone has any idea when I might be running into an issue with this on OSX.

The exact code can be found at https://gist.github.com/1861487

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: swap `exec()` for `passthru()`. This will show you the output of the command and possibly the error message.

Comment: I gave that a try earlier.  That also hangs and never returns from the AJAX call.  I have debugged it down to that exact line.  Which is strange because I can run simpler commands through like ls. dir, etc.

Comment: After further review this is known issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414647/calling-php-from-php-through-exec-gives-no-result

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I didn't find that when I searched.  Thanks again.

Comment: I did try that solution too unfortunately.  But I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the php cli you mention installed on OSX, or is it just the Apache module? Check this with php -v from terminal

Mine looks like this

```
php -v

PHP 5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Nov 15 2011 15:33:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Also can you confirm $temp_filename is set correctly using `php -l` can cause it to hang if you dont specify a path.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that.  I went as far a to alert out the command that it is trying to run and ran it.  It worked fine.

Comment: My output is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: can you confirm $temp_filename is set correctly, using php -l can cause it to hang if you dont specify a path.

Comment: If I alert out `$execute_string = 'php -l "' . $temp_filename . '"';` and run it in Terminal it works fine.  As far as I can tell the execute_string and temp_filename are working correctly.

Comment: By that I mean obviously that I alert($execute_string) so to speak after it has been formed.

Comment: yeah sorry to go over the obvious, just the way i usually troubleshoot. let me try coding it up myself and see if anything stands out

Comment: Thanks.  Hey, no problem with the obvious, any help is better then no help lol.

Comment: Hey, so i got it working on my machine by removing the double quotes around the temp file name, ill edit your gist

Comment: After reviewing this a bit more I now think your issue is in how php writes to the console on mac vs osx. OSX uses a more global context and because of this the response is not captured in the string. Windows may have written the response in a way captureable, i am looking into how to force it to use a capturable way.

Comment: Could you use http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php instead of proxying this to an exec?

Comment: The eventual goal is to have something that executes as well as heck syntax.  I just figured this first step would be simpler to do.  Also, I would like to use multiple languages so a CLI seems easier.  If you do find a better way to capture the output that would be awesome.  If not, I surely appreciate the help.

Comment: Others have had the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414647/calling-php-from-php-through-exec-gives-no-result

Comment: I tried that solution to. The program still hangs unfortunately on the exec()

Comment: Thats odd, because I dont get a hang, it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe jQuery .ajax() gets pissed when you try and return a blank value.  Nope, that isn't it.  Even trying to run that command alone gets it to hang.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working.  The problem was a few-fold.

First, the PHP being used was in /etc/bin instead of the MAMP version.  I was able to change this and use the MAMP version instead.

Second, to use php via the CLI you have to make sure to use the FULL path to `php` and not just `php` itself.  I.e. use `/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.x/php` in your exec() call.  This is now working for me.

I uploaded my GIST for it at: https://gist.github.com/1861487