# Running at from PHP gives no output

Tags: php, exec

I've been wrestling with `exec()`, trying to capture the output from it when I add a task using the `at` Unix system command. My problem is that it is giving no output when run from my script, however running it from the terminal *and* PHP in interactive mode prints out a couple of lines.

The command I want to execute is this:

```
echo exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes", $result);
```

`var_dump()` gives `string(0) ""`, and `print_r()` spits out `Array ()`. I've tried using `shell_exec()`, which outputs `NULL`, however the following outputs `hi` when run in a web page context:

```
echo exec("echo 'hi'");
```

This also outputs stuff:

```
echo exec("atq");
```

However, as soon as I use `at`, nothing is output. How can I get the output of:

```
exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes", $result);
```

Because at present it outputs nothing when run as "normal" by PHP through Apache, however running the command in the terminal as well as in PHP's interactive console gives me the expected result of something like:

```
php > echo exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes", $result);
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1219 at Sun Jun 10 12:43:00 2012
```

`safe_mode` is off, and I cannot work out why I don't get any output from `at` with a piped-in echo statement, when executing `atq` or any other commend with `exec()` gives me output. I've searched and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414647/calling-php-from-php-through-exec-gives-no-result), all to no avail.

How can I get `exec()` to return the output from `at` to either a string, or an array if using a second argument with `exec()`?

Comment: Smells like seLinux or other permission issue. Does the task even get scheduled despite not seeing any output?

Comment: Yeah, it gets scheduled even with no output. Running `sudo atq` lists the new task.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Working, one line solution

I didn't realise it could be this simple. All that is required is to reroute stderr to stdout by putting `2>&1` at the end of the command to execute. Now any output from `at` is printed to stdout, therefore captured by `exec()`:

```
echo exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes 2>&1", $result);
```

---

#### My old solution:

I was trying to keep to a one/two line solution, however the only thing that worked in the end was using `proc_open()` **because `at` logs to stderr, which `exec()` doesn't read!** I'd like to thank @Tourniquet for pointing this out, however he has deleted his answer. To quote:

> As far as i can see, at outputs to stderr, which isn't captured by
>   exec. I'm not really confident in it, but consider using
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php, which allows you to
>   direct stderr to its own pipe.

This is actually the correct way of doing things. My solution (because I only want stderr) was to do this:

```
// Open process to run `at` command
$process = proc_open("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes", array(2 => array("pipe", "w")), $pipes);

// Get stuff from stderr, because `at` prints out there for some odd reason
if(is_resource($process)) {
    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[2], 100);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

`$output` now contains whatever `at` printed to stderr (which should really go to stdout because it's not an error), and `$return_value` contains `0` on success.

Comment: @Jack What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean `echo exec("echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes 2>&1", $result);`

Comment: @Jack It works perfectly. Couldn't you have posted that earlier and saved me a few hours of struggling? `;)`

Comment: Oh no! Sorry, I had to choose between SO and Pirates of the Carribean ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Here a more complex solution with **proc_open**. I'm writing this answer because, in my case, the *'2>&1'* workaround doesn't work.

```
function runCommand($bin, $command = '', $force = true)
{
    $stream = null;
    $bin .= $force ? ' 2>&1' : '';

    $descriptorSpec = array
    (
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
        1 => array('pipe', 'w')
    );

    $process = proc_open($bin, $descriptorSpec, $pipes);

    if (is_resource($process))
    {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $command);
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        $stream = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

        proc_close($process);
    }

    return $stream;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
// getting the mime type of a supplied file
echo runCommand('file -bi ' . escapeshellarg($file));
```

Another example using the **command** parameter:

```
// executing php code on the fly
echo runCommand('/usr/bin/php', '<?php echo "hello world!"; ?>');
```

Another example using the **force** parameter (this can be useful for commands that will change the output during the execution process):

```
// converting an mp3 to a wav file
echo runCommand('lame --decode ' . escapeshellarg($source) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($dest), '', true);
```

I hope this helps **:-)**

Comment: Thanks for showing the lame example! doing exactly that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a minimum (non-)working example. Break everything down, and test only one thing at a time.

Here is one error in your bash:

```
hpek@melda:~/temp$ echo 'php -f /path/to/file.php foo=1' | at now + 1 minutes
at: pluralization is wrong
job 22 at Sun Jun 10 14:48:00 2012
hpek@melda:~/temp$
```

Write `minute` instead og `minutes`.

My output from `at` is send to me by mail!!

Comment: By the post office or fedex?