# Get Children PID using Parent PID from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec, pid

For context: I am spawning a Java application from PHP, using `xvfb-run`. Now, this process creates a parent PID for the `xvfb-run` and couple more children PIDs corresponding to `Xvfb` and `java` process.

Using the following command, I have managed to get the parent PID (of `xvfb-run`):

```php
$cmd1 = 'nohup xvfb-run -a java -jar some.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
$res1 = trim(shell_exec($cmd1));

var_dump($res1);  // Returns the parent PID. For eg: 26266
```

Now, once the Java process is complete, I will need to kill the Java process, to free up my server resources. (Java application is GUI based, and I have managed to get it working without utilising GUI control, but still I can close it, only by using `kill -9 <pid>`

Now, from the terminal, [I can get the Children **pid**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743940/2469308) using:

```sh
pgrep -P 26266
```

and, it will return me pids as follows:

```
26624
26633
```

However, when I try to do the same using PHP, I cannot get these pid(s) out. I have tried `exec`, `shell_exec`, `system` etc. My attempted script is:

```php
$cmd2 = 'pgrep -P ' . $res1;
var_dump($cmd2);
$res2 = trim(exec($cmd2, $o2, $r2));
var_dump($res2);
var_dump($o2);
var_dump($r2);
```

It prints out the following:

```
string(14) "pgrep -P 26266" string(0) "" array(0) { } int(1)
```

What am I missing here ? Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Never dealt with all these but what does `pgrep -P 27342` on the terminal give? Initially you got the result with `26266`

Comment: @nice_dev it was a typo. Edited. I have given dummy pid(s) for problem statement. Whatever parent pid I get, I can access the child pid(s), when I run it in terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running at from PHP gives no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968661/running-at-from-php-gives-no-output)

Comment: @nice_dev Tried but does not work. It seems that there is some limitation with `pgrep` approach. I have managed to solve this using `ps --ppid` approach. Will add an answer soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pgrep -P` approach did not work when doing `exec` inside PHP. So, I used [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744064/2469308) to get children pid(s):

```sh
ps --ppid <pid of the parent>
```

The sample PHP code would be:

```php
// Get parent pid and children pid in an array
$pids = [3551]; // Add parent pid here. Eg: 3551

// Call the bash command to get children pids and store in $ps_out variable
exec('ps --ppid ' . $pids[0], $ps_out);

// Loop and clean up the exec response to extract out children pid(s)
for($i = 1; $i <= count($ps_out) - 1; $i++) {
    $pids[] = (int)(preg_split('/\s+/', trim($ps_out[$i]))[0]);
}

var_dump($pids); // Dump to test the result
```