# How to deal with CLI programs that break the way that output is supposed to be returned?

Tags: php, windows, windows-10, output, command-line-interface

All too often, I encounter a crucial but badly designed program that "breaks the output". It doesn't actually return its output to PHP's functions that execute the terminal command, but "force-output" it on the command line, separate from the returned data (which is empty).

For example, `pdftotext.exe -v` results in **empty** return data, but this text (which should be its return data) is outputted:

```
pdftotext version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

Doesn't matter if you use the `-q` option.

How to force software like this to not "separate-output" what should be its return data? And why/how do they even do this in the first place? I don't get how it's technically possible.

Code example:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.03\bin64\pdftotext.exe" -v'));
```

Output:

```
pdftotext version 4.03 [www.xpdfreader.com]
Copyright 1996-2021 Glyph & Cog, LLC
NULL
```

Comment: Any PHP code example ?

Comment: @AymDev Yes. I added it in now.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `shell_exec` returns STDOUT and the executed program writes to STDERR, but that seems weird for a version command. Already tried to redirect STDERR using `2>&1` ?

Comment: @AymDev No, but I just tried that after you suggested it, and it works now. So it must be sent to "STDERR", I guess. How stupid. Can I somehow automatically grab ALL output so I don't need to remember the `2>&1` syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running at from PHP gives no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968661/running-at-from-php-gives-no-output)

Comment: Maybe using [proc_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) which seems to have pipes configuration but I'm not really sure. Anyway you can write a PHP function I guess.